# file.exists not working in R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R Shiny and I am trying to find whether a particular file exists or not. My code works properly in R (gives positive result) but when I try to work the same code in shiny, it gives negative result.

Code:

```
if(isTRUE(file.exists("temp.rds"))){
print("File Present")
}else{
print("File Not Present")
}
```

Output in R: File Present

Output in Shiny: File Not Present

I think, there is some fundamental concept which I am not understanding in Shiny. Kindly help.

Comment: Shiny working directory is where the ui.R and server.R files are

Comment: `file.exists()` returns a logical so you don't have to put it inside `isTRUE()`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by HubertL, shiny working directory is where the ui and server files are. This should work:

```
if(isTRUE(file.exists("./www/temp.rds"))){
print("File Present")
}else{
print("File Not Present")
}
```